# Neumann boundary conditions in the Maccormack scheme

Tags: pde, finite-difference, boundary-conditions, nonlinear-equations, hyperbolic-pde

I am trying to solve the viscous Burger equation
$$
\frac{\partial u}{\partial t} + u\frac{\partial u}{\partial x} = \mu \frac{\partial^2 u}{\partial x^2}
$$
with Neumann boundary conditions. I am
using the Maccormack predictor-corrector scheme:
$$
u_j^\overline{{n+1}} = u_j^n - \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}(F_{j+1} - F_j^n) + r(u_{j+1}^n - 2u_{j}^n + u_{j-1}^n )\\
u_j^{n+1} = \frac{1}{2}\Big[ u_j^n + u_j^\overline{{n+1}}  - \frac{\Delta t}{\Delta x}(F_{j}^\overline{{n+1}} - F_{j-1}^\overline{{n+1}} ) + r(u_{j+1}^\overline{{n+1}}  - 2u_{j}^\overline{{n+1}}  + u_{j-1}^\overline{{n+1}} ) \Big]
$$
for $F=0.5u^2$. I understand that the diffusive term has been centre-differenced, and I believe I implement the boundary conditions in this term by solving for a ghost node. For example, if 0 is my first real node, I say that the ghost node at $j=-1$ should satisfy $u_{-1}=u_{1}$, and I impose
$$
u_0^\overline{{n+1}} = \,... \,+ r(2 u_{1}^n - 2u_{0}^n ).
$$
My questions:

1. Is this correct?
2. How do I implement the no-flux condition with the forwards (backwards) differenced terms in the predictor (corrector) step?

Simply setting everything involving $F$ to zero doesn't seem to work.